# acra-mail 5 send email

Tags: android, acra

I just upgraded my use of ACRA to 5.1.3. Now I'm getting various build errors which I am not finding any documentation for.

More specifically, I'm using the dependencies

```
implementation 'ch.acra:acra-mail:5.1.3'
implementation "ch.acra:acra-dialog:5.1.3"
```

With the prior version, ACRA would build an email and, using an intent, send an email report. Apparently they changed substantially the syntax and methodology of doing that. As much as I've searched, I'm not finding any documntation on how to use mail + dialog. Anyone know?

In the old version, I needed a annotation:

```
@ReportsCrashes (
  reportSenderFactoryClasses = {CrashSenderFactory.class},
  mailTo = "log@xxx.com",
  mode = ReportingInteractionMode.DIALOG,
  reportDialogClass = SendLog.class,
  resDialogTheme = R.style.AppTheme_Dialog
)
```

Apparently, there's a new way to do this.

Comment: https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Migrating

Comment: Do you know specifically how to migrate ReportsCrashes? It's not mentioned in that link.

Answer (score 0):

```
@AutoService(ReportSenderFactory.class)
public class CrashSenderFactory {
...
}
```

See https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Custom-Extensions#registering-an-extension

```
@AcraMailSender(mailTo = "log@xxx.com")
@AcraDialog(reportDialogClass = SendLog.class, resTheme = R.style.AppTheme_Dialog)
public class MyApplication extends Application {
        @Override
        protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
            super.attachBaseContext(base);
            ACRA.init(this);
        }
}
```

See https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup#configuring-acra---compile-time